# Syntax error, cant use struct in c++ class

Tags: c++, class, struct

I am currently learning C++ and working on a assignment which asks me to create:

> Class student (must be separated by .h and .cpp) that inherits class person that has: 
> **a. Attributes:** dynamic array of struct holding courses and their grades and other attributes  
> **b. Member functions:** display the grade of a given course and other member functions as as needed

So, to start, I have already created the class person; so don't worry about the inheritance nor classes, my only problem is with structs, here is my code:

### student.h

```
#include <string>
#ifndef student_h
#define student_h
#include "person.h"
class student: public person {

private:
        struct stud {
            int age;
        };

public:
        student();
        int getAge();
};

#endif
```

### student.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "student.h"


student::student() {


}

int student::getAge() {

    return stud.age;
}
```

So, my logic is, in the same way, that if you define a private integer in the .h file and use it freely in the .cpp file, I should do it for the struct. When I try to compile `student.cpp` for synthax error before running `main.cpp`, I get this error:

> .\student.cpp(14) : error C2275: 'student::stud' : illegal use of this type as an expression

which is referring to `return stud.age;`. I am using (and forced to use) Visual Studio 2005.

How do I retrieve the age of the struct using a function? Also, what does my teacher mean by an array of structs? Does it mean I have to create the array in the main and how?

Comment: The nested class definition (the struct) is just that. It doesn't declare a data member of that type. By the way, the prefix `get` is just annoying verbiage in C++. You would not write `getCos(x)` for the cosine function, would you? Likewise, just `age` is fine to access or compute the age. Oh, and better store the birth year, not the age. Or else the data will get outdated fast.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nested class `stud` defines a new type, not a variable of that type. If you wish to make a variable of type `stud`, declare a separate member for it, like this:

```
class student: public person {
private:
        struct stud_t {
            int age;
        };
        stud_t stud;
public:
        student();
        int getAge();
};
```

Now `stud_t` is the name of the type, and `stud` is the name of a variable of that type.

Alternatively, you could make `stud` an *anonymous* `struct`, like this:

```
class student: public person {
private:
        struct {
            int age;
        } stud;
public:
        student();
        int getAge();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, my problem is solved and I understand now.
You rock \m/

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to store stuff in an internal struct (I don't think you should) then you could write your struct like this:

```
struct {
    int age;
} stud;
```

In your example, you're declaring a struct of *type* `stud` but then not creating an *instance*. In the snippet above, I declare an anonymous struct (ie it's *type* has no name) and then create an *instance* called `stud`.
Your current `getAge` should work if you make this change.

'dynamic array' == vector